# How does Firebase handle cross origin issues?

Tags: cross-domain, real-time-updates, firebase

Looking through the [Firebase](http://www.firebase.com) FAQ I can't see how cross domain issues are handled. Obviously, we don't want to serve on the Firebase domain, is it [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing), hidden iFrame, other? Would we need to create a sub-domain that points at the IP of the sharing server?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Let me answer this question in two parts, as there are multiple ways to communicate with the Firebase Servers.

- **Firebase JavaScript Client** - The Firebase Javascript Client maintains a real-time bidirectional connection to the server.  Under the covers, this uses WebSockets whenever possible (which have no limitations with regard to cross-origin connections) and falls back to hidden-iframe-based jsonp long-polling on older browsers (which sidesteps cross-origin issues by only doing  requests).
- **Firebase REST API** - You can also get / set data from Firebase using the REST API, which uses CORS to allow cross-origin requests.

So in summary, it should "just work" and you don't need to do anything special.

Comment: can you please elaborate on "hidden-iframe-based jsonp long-polling"

Comment: @KJW woudl be good to know but I believe it is their secret sauce. Now at least you have some pointers :)

Comment: What does not work with firebase is cross origin authentication. Instead the user has to authenticate again on every subdomain which seems to be a big missing feature.