# Ajax / Firebase only works on localhost (same-origin policy?)

Tags: javascript, ajax, same-origin-policy, firebase

I have a Firebase app that works perfectly on localhost, but does not work when I reach it externally (by allowing port forwarding in my router) or when I upload it to Bluehost.

This code works:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#button").click(function() {
        alert('Working!');
    });
});
```

but this does not:

```
var firebaseRef = new Firebase('[my firebase url]');

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#button").click(function() {
        alert('Working!');
    });
});
```

After doing some research, I believe the problem to be the [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript), since the Firebase JS include is

```
http://static.firebase.com/demo/firebase.js
```

but my firebase reference is on

```
http://gamma.firebase.com/
```

I've found a few ways to get around this but want to know the best way to handle it with Firebase (or if the Same Origin Policy is even the issue here).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer - just a dumb mistake on my part.

While searching through the Firebase tutorials, I caught my mistake. I was including the `http://static.firebase.com/demo/firebase.js` file, while the tutorial clearly says to include the `http://static.firebase.com/v0/firebase.js` file.

I am still curious as to why the `demo` file worked only on localhost...

Answer (score 2):

Firebase uses CORS for the RESTful API and WebSockets for the JS clients, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10710635/how-does-firebase-handle-cross-origin-issues), so that's not an issue.

Looks like a problem related to the routing. Are you experiencing errors in the JavaScript console? "Does not work" is a bit abstract and a more precise error could help answer the secondary question.

Comment: Agreed!  A precise error (or link to a page that reproduces the issue) would help here.